# Is It Posssible To Access AwesomePlayer Info And Error Messages From An Application?

Tags: android-mediaplayer

I'm an untrained, newbie code hacker playing with a homebrew `MediaPlayer` for streaming live internet audio. An old fashioned "radio" if you will. I'm using `OnInfo`, `OnError` and `OnBuffferingUpdate` info to fill a "status" `textView` box on my player, but I see so much more detailed info in `logcat` from the `AwesomePlayer` engine. Is it possible to access the `AwesomePlayer` info directly from the application?

Comment: I have answered your question. Can you please be more specific on what further information you would require and the objective for the same? This would help me to further refine my answer and help you.

Comment: Thank you Ganesh, that does answer my question. I was interested in possibly using the more detailed cache, and bitrate information that seems to be available.

Comment: @user725830.. By cache, are you referring to the `NuCachedSource2` implementation for a streaming source like `HTTP` and similarly `getBitrate` which essentially gives the data rate of the connection? Thanks for accepting the answer

Answer (score 4):

From an application perspective (assuming the application is written in `JAVA`), `MediaPlayer` is the abstraction for all player engines. There are multiple player engines such as `StagefrightPlayer` which internally uses `AwesomePlayer` and `NuPlayer` to name a couple.

The information made available on `listeners` i.e. `onInfoListener`, `onBufferingUpdateListener`, `onErrorListener` originates from `AwesomePlayer` which is translated into a generic message and is communicated through the `listeners`. This information is deemed to be sufficient for any application developer to develop their code around the same.

`AwesomePlayer` logs are more from `debug` perspective and helps to understand the underlying implementation of the engine. I feel that this information is good to know and understand, but not sure if this is essential for application development.

To summarize, `AwesomePlayer` information is actually communicated through the `listeners` which are generic in nature and rest of the `logcat` information is more for `debug` or understanding purposes. Currently, there is no scheme to get this information unless the developer explicitly customizes the `AOSP` distribution.

Comment: I use MediaPlayer on Sumsung S3, Sometimes, mediaplayer can not play the video,  appear a black view to me. The logcat log is :
I/AwesomePlayer( 1899): we're much too late (0.51 secs), video skipping ahead
Could you help me?

Comment: @dragonfly The reason for the log `we're much too late` means that the video is lagging behind the audio. This log is from audio-video synchronization. Does this happen to a specific video or for all videos? Maybe for this format (I expect this to be low priority), the decoding is on CPU due to which video may be slow. If you can share more information, I can provide better help.

Comment: It happens on sumsung s3, I did not find it happened on other devices.

This happened to an arbitrary h264/aac video on S3.

Comment: @dragonfly.. Can you please share the logs? Is this reproducible always or only under specific conditions?

Comment: OK, I will paste the whole log. It is reproducible always on S3.

Comment: I have collected the log when error occur.http://yunpan.taobao.com/s/UoM58BOW0H
This is reproducible on my s3 device and the chance is about 10%.
my device info: GT-I9300 android4.4.4 11-20141115-snapshot-m12-i9300